# How to play pre-recorded audio in reverse direction, using AudioTrak / AudioRekord IPA and Multithreading

Tags: multithreading, android-asynctask, audiorecord, audiotrack

First I write down 10 seconds of audio at the touch of a button1.
Then I want to play this record **backwards** by pressing a button2.
The logic is clear to me, but I can not figure out which method is responsible for reverse playback.

**P.S.** I will do everything with Thread or AsyncTask.